# How to set Dialog width and height in percents in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout, android-dialogfragment

I need my Dialog width and height fill 70% of screen space. I'm using `ConstraintLayout` as root layout and tried to achieve this by using `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` but it's not working.

It would be great to achieve this in `XML` without Java code.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_shape"
    android:padding="@dimen/app_padding">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        style="@style/text_plain3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/add_member_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_add_member_close"
        style="@style/text_title2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_dialog_close"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="X"
        android:textColor="@color/text_plain3"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_member_group_id"
        style="@style/text_group_id"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        style="@style/text_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/add_member_annotation"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/add_member_user_id"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/add_member_hint_id"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:maxLength="28"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_member"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:text="@string/add_member_button_add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_member_user_id"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In order to have a constraint width/height DialogFragment or (any specific width or height in general):**

1. wrap your `ConstraintLayout` into another `ConstraintLayout` in order to make the outer take the full size of the screen, and the inner get the desired width/height percentage:
2. Make the `android:background` of the outer to be transparent
3. Constraint the width & height of the inner `ConstraintLayout`, make it centered in parent, and add the percentage constraint to the width & height:

   ```
   app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.7"
   app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
   ```

Now the layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout      
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"        
        android:padding="@dimen/app_padding">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            style="@style/text_plain3"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="@string/add_member_title"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button_add_member_close"
            style="@style/text_title2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_dialog_close"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="X"
            android:textColor="@color/text_plain3"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_member_group_id"
            style="@style/text_group_id"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            style="@style/text_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/add_member_annotation"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_member_group_id" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_member_user_id"
            android:layout_width="248dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/add_member_hint_id"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="28"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView17" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add_member"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            android:text="@string/add_member_button_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/add_member_group_id"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/add_member_user_id" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

4. In your custom DialogFragment:

- Designate the width & height of the dialog to `MATCH_PARENT`:

```
dialog?.window?.setLayout(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
)
```

- Set no background the theme:

```
<style name="NoBackgroundDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

**Custom Dialog Fragment:**

Java:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.dialog_layout, container,
                false
        );
    }

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // Making the dialog full screen
        if (getDialog() != null)
            getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.dialog_layout, container,
            false
        )
    }

    override fun getTheme(): Int = R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Making the dialog full screen
        dialog?.window?.setLayout(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )

    }

}
```

Note: I am assuming that the dialog layout is `R.layout.dialog_layout`
[image]

**UPDATE**

> now if I click on empty space around the Dialog, it doesn't close.

This is because the dialog fragment consumes the entire screen size; you can solve this by the below workaround:

- Add an ID to the outer most `ConstraintLayout`, assume it is `root` >> Updated on the top layout
- Add an ID to the inner `ConstraintLayout`, assume it is `main_layout` >> Updated on the top layout
- Dismiss the dialog when the `root` is clicked
- Do nothing when the `main_layout` is clicked to consume the event so that it won't be dismissed:

So, update the `onStart()` of the `MyDialogFragment` to:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // Making the dialog full screen
    dialog?.window?.setLayout(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    )

    
    val root = requireView().findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)
    root.setOnClickListener {
        dismiss() // Dismiss the dialog
    }
    
    val main = requireView().findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main_layout)
    main.setOnClickListener {
        // Consume the event
    }

}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But there is a problem - now if I click on empty space around the Dialog, it doesn't close. In my opinion that is because there is no physical empty space, but only visual, because the parent `ConstraintLayout` width and height are set to `match_parent`.

Comment: @RomanKnyazev Please check UPDATE section in the answer, hope it is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

**ConstraintLayout:**

I see your "Dialog" Box contains a lot of different views. For that I made a simple example for you to show how to use `Guideline` for achieving percentages of `Views`.
I suggest to learn how this works and rebuild your `layout` with better constraining on this `Guidelines`, because now everything is wired up really bad. The idea will be to wire the `ConstraintLayout` to the `Guideline` and everything beside that (e.g. `TextView` etc.) to the `ConstraintLayout`. (Without Hardcoding!, that's how relative design work).

My example shows a `TextView` (could be your `ConstraintLayout` (frame for everything) that has exactly 70% (`app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7"`) vertically and horizontal of the screen. Important is to set the `TextViews` `width` and `height` to `0dp` and to attach to the `Guideline`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#2962FF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/vertical_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="TextView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: 70% equal on both]

In addition same for **LinearLayout:**

You can use `android:layout_weight=""` to give a percent amount. So 70% means a `weight` of `.70`.

Keep in mind to set the `width` or/and `height` to `0dp`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="70 percent of screen" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".70" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That doesn't work for Dialog. I am just getting darkened screen (dialog background) when I open the Dialog. To use Guidelines for defining dialog box sizes, root layout size has to be equal to parent. In my opinion that's the problem. In original code root layout size was equal to size of Dialog box.

Comment: What do you mean with Dialog? Is it a name of a widget? In your code I see only some TextViews and Layouts that will look like a "Dialog" but it's a synonym and no widget. You have 2 options given in my answer. To work with ConstraintLayout or LinearLayout. Everything you want to achieve is possible with that. If you have other code with Dialog, then provide it please. In your question there is no Dialog at all :)